# Convert nested object to array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object

I would like to convert my below object to a specific format see..

my Object is look like

```
{
  "RecruiterInfo": {
    "Person": {
      "FirstName": "vals ererererre123",
      "LastName": "ravl2422",
      "CreatedOn": "1900-01-01T00:00:00",
      "Worktelephone": "",
      "PhoneNo": "9586391750",
      "Email": "vil@mailinator.comm",
      "UserId": {
        "Password": "Vm0wd2QyUXlWa1pOVldScFVtMVNjRlZ0TVZOWFJsbDNXa2M1VjJKSGVEQmFWVll3VjBaS2RHVkljRmRXTTJoeVZtMHhTMUl5VGtsaVJtUlhUVEZLVFZac1ZtRldNVnBXVFZWV2FHVnFRVGs9",
        "Status": 1,
        "ID": 1
      },
      "ID": 31
    },
    "CompanyName": "Teenr1242424",
    "Designation": "PM125554242",
    "BusinessType": 1179,
    "OrganizationSize": 1119,
    "IsVIP": 1
  }
}
```

I would like to convert above object to

```
[
  {
    AppFieldID: "CompanyName",
    Value: "Teenr1242424"
  },
  {
    AppFieldID: "Designation",
    Value: "PM125554242"
  },
  {
    AppFieldID: "BusinessType",
    Value: 1179
  },
  {
    AppFieldID: "OrganizationSize",
    Value: 1179
  },
  {
    AppFieldID: "IsVIP",
    Value: 1
  },
  {
    AppFieldID: "Person",
    Value: [
      {
        AppFieldID: "FirstName",
        Value: "vals ererererre123"
      },
      {
        AppFieldID: "ID",
        Value: 1
      },
      {
        AppFieldID: "CreatedOn",
        Value: "1900-01-01T00:00:00"
      },
      {
        AppFieldID: "Email",
        Value: "vil@mailinator.comm"
      },
      {
        AppFieldID: "LastName",
        Value: "ravl2422"
      },
      {
        AppFieldID: "WorkTelephone",
        Value: ""
      },
      {
        AppFieldID: "PhoneNo",
        Value: "9586391750"
      },
      {
        AppFieldID: "UserId",
        Value: [
          {
            AppFieldID: "ID",
            Value: 1
          },
          {
            AppFieldID: "Password",
            Value: "Vm0wd2QyUXlWa1pOVldScFVtMVNjRlZ0TVZOWFJsbDNXa2M1VjJKSGVEQmFWVll3VjBaS2RHVkljRmRXTTJoeVZtMHhTMUl5VGtsaVJtUlhUVEZLVFZac1ZtRldNVnBXVFZWV2FHVnFRVGs9"
          },
          {
            AppFieldID: "Status",
            Value: 1
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

it should be a dynamic code, because in feature there will be multiple nested object

can anyone help for convert that object to above array

I tried to convert it by using some nested loop and making recursive function, but i am not able to convert.

thanks
kj

Comment: _"I tried to convert"_ show your attempt, SO is more for helping teach you how to fix your code than generating a whole new piece of code for you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I hope this would help, let me know if there is a problem, 
if you want to know more do a research on `recursion`:

```
function convertObject(input) {
  const newObj =  Object.keys(input).map(key => {
    let Value = "";
    if(typeof input[key]=== 'object') {
      Value = convertObject(input[key])
    } else {
      Value = input[key];
    }
    return { AppFieldID: key, Value }
  });
  return newObj;
}
convertObject(yourObject.RecruiterInfo));
```

Comment: hey meisam it is working as expected, thanks for help

yes i would like to do a research on recursion